# Pandas dataframe - Formatting certain rows or cells to 2 d.p

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format

With the following dataframe, I would like to reformat the first two rows to 2 decimal places.

```
       A         B    C        D     E   F
0     68        45        1843.4    98
1  978.1             23              3    
2                                  
3          49889.2   80
```

I have tried methods such as:

```
df.iloc[0:1,:].style.format("{0:.2f}")
```

For other projects I would also like to format certain cells, such as col B, index 3 to 49889.20 (2 d.p.), would a similar approach be used for this?

Thanks for any help

**Additional Info:**
For some context to what I am doing, I am creating a mixed string/float dataframe to be printed via pylatex to LaTeX tex and PDF document (see PDF output below). The pdf prints the actual dataframe, so the PDF shows the dataframe identically as it would output in python. 
I would like to display the values to 2 d.p. as they are financial numbers. Preferably this will be edited in the dataframe, rather than in the pylatex process. i.e. so pylatex simply prints the dataframe. All calculations will have been completed before publishing PDF, so there is no issue turning the values into strings. Thanks. 
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Values are changed to strings, but it is possible:

```
df.iloc[:2] = df.iloc[:2].applymap('{0:.2f}'.format)
print (df)
      A        B      C        D      E    F
0  0.00    68.00  45.00  1843.40  98.00  nan
1  1.00   978.10  23.00     3.00    nan  nan
2     2      NaN    NaN      NaN    NaN  NaN
3     3  49889.2     80      NaN    NaN  NaN
```

EDIT: For custom function with `try-except` use:

```
def func(x):
    try:
        return '{0:.2f}'.format(x)
    except:
        return x

df = df.applymap(func)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added some additional info to the question which hopefully will be helpful in providing some context. Do you think it would be possible to complete some sort of for and try loops - for rows and cols, try format "{0:.2f}} except if error/string continue??

Answer (score 1):

To build on @jezrael's answer, you can pass a dictionary for the columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import string

#create some random data
df = pd.DataFrame({k:v for k,v in zip(list(string.ascii_uppercase[:5]), np.random.random_sample((5,5)))})

       A            B           C           D           E
0   0.995053    0.032561    0.556866    0.565944    0.613636
1   0.586174    0.932380    0.567946    0.277729    0.883482
2   0.210020    0.992571    0.626377    0.070947    0.723614
3   0.478476    0.866163    0.197633    0.621722    0.532891
4   0.743204    0.823418    0.616961    0.182829    0.642123
```

Then using, `df.style.format({'B': "{:.2f}", 'D': '{:+.2f}'})` will yield:

```
       A         B          C         D        E
0   0.424395    0.23    0.960664    +0.96   0.992401
1   0.414769    0.57    0.664916    +0.73   0.850706
2   0.147415    0.88    0.873205    +0.12   0.33699
3   0.3742      0.28    0.496887    +0.74   0.885727
4   0.270247    0.67    0.501478    +0.10   0.113295
```

For completeness:

```
def conditional_formatter(value):
    return "{:.2f}".format(value) if not isinstance(value, str) else value

df.applymap(conditional_formatter)
```

Comment: Thanks Fourier, I have added some additional info to the question which hopefully will be helpful in providing some context.

Answer (score 0):

Formatting rows in a pandas DataFrame is quite odd as the types are standardly defined per column, maybe changing this (orientation) might help.
What might work is the .Round() method which can be called on DataFrames.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.round.html

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I have added some additional info to my question which might help provide some more context. Sadly the round method didn't work in my case.